# List comparison "==" vs "in" with elementtree

Tags: python, elementtree

I have an XML I am parsing, and two elements have the same name, but require a unique value for each out of two options. I am able to get the code to function as I would like, however I am not sure why one method works (`in`) and the other does not (`==`).

XML snippet:

```
<metaMetadata>
    <metadataSchema>Value1</metadataSchema>
    <metadataSchema>Value2</metadataSchema>
</metaMetadata>
```

code:

```
schema_val = ['Value1', 'Value2']

for ele in root.findall(".//{*}metaMetadata"):
    m_schema = ele.findall("lom:metadataSchema",ns)

    m_schema_check = [i for i in schema_val if i in m_schema[0].text]
    if m_schema_check:
        for i in m_schema_check:
            schema_val.remove(i)
            if m_schema[1].text in schema_val:
                print('pass')
```

This works as I would like it to, but I am trying to understand why it only works when I have `in` , and when I have `==` the code doesn't function and skips the `print`.

Comment: `in` tests membership, `==` tests equality. They are different, so it's no surprise that only one of them works.

Comment: Do you mean the `in` in `[i for i in schema_val if i in m_schema[0].text]` or in `if m_schema[1].text in schema_val:`?

Comment: How looks your required xml output? 2 times Value1?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Sorry, I should have made that more clear. I meant in the `if` statement

Comment: Please edit the question then.  *"I meant in the if statement"* — `m_schema[1].text` is a string, `schema_val` is a list of strings.  Why they should (or rather could) be equal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** Would you like compare xml list values with your schema value list? If the order of the list elements doesn't matter you can `sort()` the lists before comparison:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_str = """<metaMetadata>
    <metadataSchema>Value1</metadataSchema>
    <metadataSchema>Value2</metadataSchema>
</metaMetadata>"""

tree = ET.fromstring(xml_str)

l = [c.text for c in tree.findall('.//metadataSchema')]

schema_val = ['Value2', 'Value1']
if l.sort() == schema_val.sort():
    print('true')
else:
    print('false')
```

Output:
`true`

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) This is sorta close to what I am looking for. The big issue is that `Value1` and `Value2` are required, but they can appear in either `<metadataSchema>` tags. So `Value2` can appear first.

Comment: @Avila than you can sort the lists, before compare it. I edited my answer.